# 32bit ODBC++ dll on Windows 2008 Server 64bit

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, 64-bit, odbc, 32bit-64bit

A client of ours is trying to migrate to 64 bit Windows.  They haven't got an ODBC++ dll present and our solution linked against the version shipped with 2003 server (32-bit).

However, when looking at the 32-bit ODBC++ dll migrated from Windows 2003 to Windows 2008 in dependency walker it seems to be invalid. Can anyone suggest how I can get the 32-bit ODBC++ dll working in a 64 bit Windows 2008 enviroment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end we had to relink against a 64bit API for ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look in the c:\windows\sysWOW64 folder. It should contain the 32bit version of the odbc.dll, and the odbcad32.exe.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the Answer, ODBC++ is like an API, the ODBC.dll is different.

Comment: My mistake my brain skimmed over the ++.